# Asymptote inconsistently draws figures

Tags: asymptote

Asymptote inconsistently draws the following figure depending on what draw commands are commented out.

```
import graph3;
size(200,200,IgnoreAspect);
currentprojection=orthographic(7.2,-5.1,8);
defaultrender.merge=true;

// draw #1
draw((0,1,0)--(2,1,4)--(2,0,0)--cycle,rgb(.3,.3,.3)+linewidth(2));

path3 p1=(1,0,0)--(1,2,0)--(3,2,0)--(3,0,0);
// draw #2
draw(surface(p1 -- cycle), emissive(gray+opacity(.6)));

path3 p2=(0,1,0)--(2,1,4)--(2,0,0);
draw(surface(p2 -- cycle), emissive(gray+opacity(.6)));

path3 p3=(2,0,0)--(2,1,4)--(2,1,0);
draw(surface(p3 -- cycle), emissive(gray+opacity(.6)));
```

As is, parts of 3 planes and a closed path in space is drawn. The planes are drawn in a light gray color.

If the draw command after `draw #2` is commented out, the two remaining planes are now drawn in black.

If the both draw commands after `draw #1` and `draw #2` are commented out, nothing is drawn.

This behavior is exhibited when I use the default Asymptote viewer and when I create a .pdf.

My default render options: `-tex "latex" -V  -render=-1`.

My .pdf render options: `-f pdf  -render=-3 -noView -noprc -antialias 2 -tex "xelatex"`

I'm using Asymptote 2.41, Ghostscript 9.21.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Generally speaking, Asymptote does not handle 3d transparency very well unless render=0.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your 3 versions of the code and view it in Adobe Acrobat Reader or SumatraPDF I see the following images.  I used all your render options with Asymptote 2.38 and Ghostscript 9.19.  I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but maybe it will help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Knowing my Windows machine, it's probably "just me."